# How to square a mathematical expression in R?

Tags: r

I have a mathematical expression which is ;

```
> myexp <- expression(x^2 + 2*x + 1)
> 
> myexp

expression(x^2 + 2 * x + 1)
```

I'd like to square the expression but it doesn't work when I run `myexp**2` or `myexp^2`

What I want to obtain is this;

```
expression(x^4 + 4 * x^3 + 6 * x^2 + 4 * x + 1)
```

how can we do this in R ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is the `Ryacas` package, which will work with multiple variables:

```
Ryacas::yac_expr("Expand((x^2 + y^2 + 3*x + 3)^2)")
#> expression(x^4 + 6 * x^3 + (2 * y^2 + 15) * x^2 + (6 * y^2 + 
#>     18) * x + y^4 + 6 * y^2 + 9)
```

Alternatively, I just discovered the `mpoly` package:

```
mpoly::mp("x^2 + y^2 + 3*x + 3")^2
#> x^4  +  2 x^2 y^2  +  6 x^3  +  15 x^2  +  y^4  +  6 x y^2  +  6 y^2  +  18 x  +  9
```

Comment: this is looking way convenient, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

"Expressions" in R are not mathematical expressions, but rather lists of calls, symbols, etc. See the help file for `?expression`.

For what you want to accomplish, I believe you need the `polynom` package.

```
myexp <- polynom::polynomial(c(1,2,1))
myexp^2

## 1 + 4*x + 6*x^2 + 4*x^3 + x^4
```

Comment: I checked the package, thanks it seems useful but irl I have to square expressions which has multiple parameters like `x^2 + y^2 + 3*x + 3`. how can I handle this ?

Comment: I don't know.  Why not just do this on Wolfram Alpha?  https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: thanks for your advice I need to do this "in R" :)